# What's the difference between these two 'Hot corners' options?

Tags: release-freya, hot-corners

I can see in 'Hot corners' two options which apparently seem equal. In Spanish these two are called:

> Ver todas las ventanas
>
> Mostrar todas las ventanas

They are the third and second to last options in the dropdown, respectively.

In Spanish these two sentences are pretty much indistinguishable.

What do they say in English and what do they do differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They say:

Window overview => Will show only the windows on your current virtual desktop

Show all windows => Will show all the windows on all of your virtual desktops